# simulating mouse right click in my WinForm app

Tags: c#, winforms, simulation

am trying to simulate mouse right click in my `WinForm` app as follow :

```
public const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
public const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public static IntPtr MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord)
{
    return (IntPtr)((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xffff));
}

public static void Click(int x, int y)
{
    SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(x,y));
    SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_RBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(x,y));
}
```

`(x,y)` the coords inside the app window form, but nothing happens what am missing here?

EDIT: I have also tried `FindWindow(null,"Form1");` and it gives same `Handle` as `this.Handle`..

Comment: Are you using the correct handle? Your `Click()` is static and your form/window (with the `Handle` property) is an instance.

Comment: @Sjips `FindWindow(null,"Form1");` give the same handle! or there is different way?

Comment: The wParam argument indicates what buttons are down.  It should be (IntPtr)2

Comment: @HansPassant that didn't solve it....

Comment: I pasted your code in some quick and dirty WinForms app and it looks your code is okay. Maybe it is still the `Handle` property. Does your `FindWindow(null, "Form1")` find the window/form in the designer instead of the window of your app? In that case, the messages are sent to the designer Form1, not your running app Form1.

Comment: @Sjips I have tried to run the debug outside the designer, same result..

Comment: Probably that is not enough. You should completely shut off VS in your case and run the App from your debug folder. And be sure that no other application uses a "Form1". Maybe it is better for this testing purpose to use a caption of your form that is unique, for example `MixedCodersForm`.

Comment: Other approach: use Spy++ to see if the messages are really arriving. Spy++ can be reached from VS menu bar, Tools.

Comment: @Sjips I have tried that too, but still not working!

Comment: When you add in `Click` the line `Debug.WriteLine("Sending to " + this.Handle.ToString("X8"));` you can see where the simulated messages are send to. Rightclick with the mouse in the window and observe by Spy++ if the real messages are sent to the same handle as in your `Click(...)`.

Comment: @Sjips yes it's the same handler!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Why you dont use the Events built-in in Windows Forms??

Use de MouseDown Event of any control, example the Form:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {

            }
        }
```

The MouseDown Event take the control in a any mouse button pressed.